# wheel demo not working

Tags: android, android-wheel

I have the `kankan.wheel` demo (cities, passwords, date/time etc.) and its working fine.

I wrote a small program to see if I can use it by myself:

This is how the class begins:

```
public class WheelTestActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    WheelView wheel = (WheelView)findViewById(R.id.passw_1);
```

I put a breakpoint at `setContentView(R.layout.main);`
This is the row that causes the problem.

I receive an error :

> Could not find class `kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView`, referenced from method com.example.WheelTestActivity.onCreate

I noticed that the file "wheel.jar" on the original demo is placed under: "Android Dependencies" folder of the project
In my project, the file "wheel.jar" is under "lib" folder

Is that the problem ?

Comment: yes, you should configure your build path to include either wheel.jar, or complete library project

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your Folder name from **lib** to **libs** if you have updated ADT 17. See [here](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17)  for in detail information on this topic.

If you are still having the same problem after changing the folder name do the following:

1. In Eclipse go to Properties -> Java build path -> Order and export.
2. Mark your jar file (wheel.jar).
3. Move jar to top of the list.

Comment: Vote up requires 15 reputation....Sorry I cannot vote UP

Its AMAZING - I changed the folder name from LIB to LIBS

All is working good!

Comment: I'm glad that my answer worked on your problem. I think at least you are able to [accept the answer] (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which is enough for now.